# What could cause a PHP insert into a MYSQL database to wrongly insert data from another user into a row?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

A student of mine was saving her score for a learning game to a MySQL database but somehow a different person's name ended up being stored in her database row. How is this possible? Here is the PHP for the insert.

```
// Get Configuration file
require "configenzymatic.php";

// Connect to your server

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Status Checker
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ($_GET["status"]) {
    echo "online";
    exit;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Upload new score
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//set POST data as data to be checked and updated
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$level1right = $_POST['level1right'];
$level1wrong = $_POST['level1wrong'];
$level2right = $_POST['level2right'];
$level2wrong = $_POST['level2wrong'];
$level3right = $_POST['level3right'];
$level3wrong = $_POST['level3wrong'];
$level4right = $_POST['level4right'];
$level4wrong = $_POST['level4wrong'];

// check for email and set hash variable
$stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tname WHERE email=?");
$stm->bindValue(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();

while ($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $hashes = array($row['hash']);
    $hash = $row['hash'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    foreach ($hashes as $hash) {
        // If hash matches password, then...

        if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
            // Everything is cool -- Insert the data into the database (update)

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
UPDATE $tname 
   SET firstname = :firstname
     , lastname = :lastname
     ,  hash = :hash
     , level1right = :level1right
     , level1wrong = :level1wrong
     , level2right = :level2right
     , level2wrong = :level2wrong
     , level3right = :level3right
     , level3wrong = :level3wrong
     , level4right = :level4right
     , level4wrong = :level4wrong 
 WHERE email = :email 
   AND id = :id");
            $stmt->execute(array($firstname, $lastname, $hash, $level1right, $level1wrong, $level2right, $level2wrong, $level3right, $level3wrong, $level4right, $level4wrong, $email, $id));
            $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

            // check if row inserted

            /* Return number of rows that were updated */
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            echo "$count";
        }
    }
}
```

The student inputted her name but someone else's name got inserted. I am totally baffled by this. Does anyone have any idea how this could occur? The person whose name was inserted in place of my student's added data at 12:30:44 today and my student added her data at 13:44:15. How did this data get mixed?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but that `$tname` looks really suspicious. What is behind it? I hope it is not a separate table for each user.

Comment: Why is your update inside 2 loops?

Comment: `foreach ($hashes as $hash)`? Why? You only have one hash.

Comment: Consistent use of whitespace and indentation will make your code much easier to read; for yourself and others.

Comment: Unrelated note: you really want to be using `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8` charset in MySQL.

Comment: The probability of having 2 exact hashes and 2 exact emails is VERY low. This could be silly, but are your student and that other person set on the same computer and using the same browser ? :)

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: A schema like this is a pretty clear violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If possible try and restructure this into a one-to-many relational structure as that will make your querying it a lot easier. You'd want to have one row per answer or "level" using your terms here, and a one-to-many relationship between the student(?) and that data. It seems extremely odd to be storing this in the same table used for authentication, too.

Comment: Note that `WHERE id=:id` should be sufficient *if* you are sure that the `id` values are unique, as in `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` type values. It's not clear why you're updating all the fields each time, too, when you've read data out of them a moment before. Do they have to post their name all over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain why you had your update wrapped in multiple loops, but it's entirely possible that users with the same password hash could exist, and (I think) would explain the behaviour you're seeing.

You are, presumably, looking to update the single user with the email and password submitted in the form? I assume you also have constraints on your table to ensure that email addresses are unique. So, you're grabbing the single user that matches that email, and checking their password. If it matches, update the single record with the same database ID. No loops!

```
// get password hash
$stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, hash FROM $tname WHERE email=?");
$stm->execute([$_POST["email"]]);

$row  = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$hash = $row['hash'];
$id   = $row['id'];
if (!password_verify($_POST["password"], $hash)) {
    // verification failed, do something to present an error to the user
    die();
}
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(
    "UPDATE $tname
        SET firstname=:firstname, lastname=:lastname,
            level1right=:level1right, level1wrong=:level1wrong,
            level2right=:level2right, level2wrong=:level2wrong,
            level3right=:level3right, level3wrong=:level3wrong,
            level4right=:level4right, level4wrong=:level4wrong
        WHERE id=:id"
);
$stmt->execute([
    ":firstname"   => $_POST["firstname"],
    ":lastname"    => $_POST["lastname"],
    ":level1right" => $_POST["level1right"],
    ":level1wrong" => $_POST["level1wrong"],
    ":level2right" => $_POST["level2right"],
    ":level2wrong" => $_POST["level2wrong"],
    ":level3right" => $_POST["level3right"],
    ":level3wrong" => $_POST["level3wrong"],
    ":level4right" => $_POST["level4right"],
    ":level4wrong" => $_POST["level4wrong"],
    ":id"          => $id
]);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo "$count";
```

Also note that using named parameters in PDO requires the use of an associative array. Not sure how your original code would update anything at all without that.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I think the reason I used the loop is because I did not restrict e-mails to be unique, so the code loops through all of the hashes and selects the one for the entered email that matches the password.  So, it seems students would need to input both the same email and the same password to get mixed up.  But, the students who got mixed up had completely different emails.  Doesn't the script check to make sure the e-mails match as well as the hashes?   I am still unsure how it could get mixed up like that.  I'll update when I have more info.  I am upvoting you too.  Thanks